# Comments being reported and deactivated automatically

Tags: javascript, html

We have here a strange issue.

We have a comments form where users can submit their comment about news articles and after that submission every comment is accepted and listed in the same page.

In every comment listed we have a link that allow to report that comment. When anyone click in that link it does the following:

Step 1. It shows an alert with javascript asking to confirm the reporting (Yes or no are the possibilities).

Step 2. After the user confirm the report the comment is deactivated and hidden.

The problem is that all the comments are being reported automatically by someone or by a bot.

Do you think it's a bot? He can overcome the javascript alert? Or a user?

What do you think? Anyone can help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose (read: hope) you log the "reporting" action. Check the web server access log for one of those entries to check for the user agent; that should tell you if it's a bot (at least, if it's a "good" bot).

Comment: Anybody, bot or human, can bypass JavaScript. At some point you must be sending some information to the server to deactivate the comment, and that can easily be done without using a web browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the link have a regular href which will trigger the action? If so, then it's highly likely a bot is following it. I would also make the action a hidden POST form, submitted by javascript, since this is not really something you want driven by a GET.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paul, but I think the main problem is in your Step 2:

> Step 2. After the user confirm the
>   report the comment is deactivated and
>   hidden.

Those reports should be verified by someone before comments are censored - that will put off humans at least. You could implement a [recaptcha](http://recaptcha.net/) to make this more difficult.